Vue.js and and amplify for aws
I'm trying to connect my vue.js with cognito using amplify but I keep getting errors:
here's my aws-exports.js:
const awsconfig = {
  Auth: {
    region: 'us-east-1',
    userPoolId: 'us-east-1_mld8IjN9e',
    userPoolWebClientId: '229bq6q1fbjtp0r43hhoq5qoe7',
    authenticationFlowType: 'USER_PASSWORD_AUTH'
  }
};
export default awsconfig;

and this is my main.js:
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import {Amplify} from 'aws-amplify';
import awsconfig from './aws-exports';

console.log('AWS Config:', awsconfig);

Amplify.configure(awsconfig);
createApp(App).mount('#app')
console.log(Amplify);

and this is the error i keep getting:
ERROR
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'loginWith')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'loginWith')
    at AmplifyClass.notifyOAuthListener (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@aws-amplify/core/dist/esm/singleton/Amplify.mjs:89:44)
    at AmplifyClass.configure (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@aws-amplify/core/dist/esm/singleton/Amplify.mjs:68:10)
    at Object.configure (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/aws-amplify/dist/esm/initSingleton.mjs:52:62)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///./src/main.js:14:57)
    at ./src/main.js (http://localhost:8080/js/app.js:74:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:8080/js/app.js:435:32)
    at http://localhost:8080/js/app.js:1547:109
    at __webpack_require__.O (http://localhost:8080/js/app.js:477:23)
    at http://localhost:8080/js/app.js:1548:53
    at http://localhost:8080/js/app.js:1550:12

anyone knows the solution to this

Your awsconfig in your aws-exports.js shows you are using authenticationFlowType: 'USER_PASSWORD_AUTH'. This shouldn't trigger the reading loginWith error you currently face as it only exists in federatedSignIn which uses oAuth. You can follow the steps below to create a new User Pool. Note how I checked email and password.




Navigate to the App Client setting by scrolling to the base.

Edit the App Client Setting by adding ALLOW_USER_PASSWORD_AUTH to the Authentication flows


Save Changes


If you don't want to create a new user pool, follow the steps below to disable oAuth from your former AWS Cognito Console.

Select your User Pool
Go to App Client Settings
Uncheck all OAuth 2.0 Grant Types
Remove all Allowed OAuth Scopes
Clear any Callback URLs and Sign out URLs
Save changes

Also in your App Client Settings, ensure you do the following:

Enable only USER_PASSWORD_AUTH under Enabled Identity Providers
Disable any social identity providers
Save changes

Also, update your aws-config to :


Amplify.configure({
  Auth: {
         region: 'us-east-1',
         userPoolId: 'us-east-1_mld8IjN9e',
         userPoolWebClientId: '229bq6q1fbjtp0r43hhoq5qoe7',
         authenticationFlowType: 'USER_PASSWORD_AUTH',
         oauth: {
                  domain: 'none',
                  scope: [],
                  redirectSignIn: 'none',
                  redirectSignOut: 'none',
                  responseType: 'none',
                },
          federationDisabled: true
  }
});



I believe this just solve your issue

Thank you so much. one more question I have a custom attribute in my users table, but I couldn't figure how to access it. do you know how?

You can extract your defined custom attributes by using 'custom:<Attribute_name>'. If your custom attribute is role, you can extract it with 'custom:role'. I believe you have written a function to get your user attributes ?
